# @Valid not working with JAX-RS using Spring Boot

Tags: java, validation, jersey, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I just can't get validations to work. I have this simple endpoint that is part of an Spring Boot application:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response create(@Valid UserDTO userDTO, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    User user = UserParser.parse(userDTO);
    userService.save(user);
    final URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(String.valueOf(user.getId())).build();
    return Response.created(uri).build();
}
```

Then, the UserDTO to validate:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class UserDTO {

    private Long id;

    // redundant validations, for testing
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 80, message = "First name too short")
    @NotBlank(message = "First name blank")
    @NotEmpty(message = "First name empty")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 80, message = "Last name too short")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

}
```

And it always processes any request, even with empty fields. I even created a test endpoint to see if the problem was having the validations inside the DTO

```
@Path("/validator/{testInt}")
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String validator(@Valid @Min(value = 30, message = "testInt too small") @PathParam("testInt") Integer testInt) {
    return String.valueOf(testInt);
}
```

But that doesn't work either, it happily returns any int it receives. In case it matters, my endpoint is a `@Service`, and here is the relevant parts of my maven dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:jar:2.22.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b31:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.el:javax.el-api:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.web:javax.el:jar:2.2.4:compile
```

I also set breakpoints inside `HibernateValidator`, and saw that two of its methods get called, so looks like it's running. Just not validating.

**EDIT**: My jersey configuration

```
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(RequestContextFilter.class);
        register(LoggingFilter.class);
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
        packages("com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Validation should work out the box unless meta-inf scanning is disable, but that doesn't look like the case. But if it is, you can explicitly register the `ValidationFeature` with Jersey. If it is already working, and it is just not the response you are expecting, the reporting behavior needs to be configured. Set the property `ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE` to true in Jersey. Other than that I can't reproduce the behavior of it simply just not working, with what you've provided.

Answer (score 3):

The question was raised years ago, but for all using Stack Overflow as knowledge database, I want to record an additional solution thats works for me.

Despite contrary documentations I had to annotate the controller class with `@Validated` **and** use `@Valid` at method level in a Spring Boot (v2.1.3.RELEASE) with Hibernate (5.3.7.Final) and Hibernate Validator (6.0.14.Final) context. If one of both annotations was missing, I got also the above mentioned error scenario.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Validated
public class UserController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public User saveUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserDto user) {
    <your service call>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following configuration to your JerseyConfig method

```
public JerseyConfig()
{
    register(YourEndpoint.class);
    property(org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In case it matters, my endpoint is a @Service

Try to set the stereotype to `@Controller`

Check if this bean is defined in your Web configuration.

```
@Bean
    public javax.validation.Validator validator() {
        return new org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
```

also check if your configuration has `@EnableWebMvc` annotation

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Neither does Component.

Comment: Weird. If I add that Bean, validation doesn't work either. But if I try to Autowire the validator into my endpoint, I get `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: localValidatorFactoryBean,mvcValidator`
And if I remove the Bean and leave the Autowire, I get `No qualifying bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] found for dependency`

Comment: Adding EnableWebMvn also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

ValidationFeature is auto discoverable as per jersey 2.0. You don't have to explicitly register it.

Include the flag,         `property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true)` 
in jersey resource config for the validation message to be sent in the response.

Make sure Jersey-bean-validation.jar is on the classpath (in your case it already is).

Simple Example,

```
//Web Resource
@Path("/accounts")
public Object getaccount(@Valid @BeanParam AccountRequest);

public class AccountRequest {
@NotNull
private String accountId;
}
```

refer, https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html

Answer (score -1):

@Funtik's suggestion about making it an `@Controller` is worth a try, but I suspect your problem is that you're not handling the error in your controller.

I'm not an expert on this, so recommend you do a little further reading, but I think you need to add a BindingResult, which will be populated in the event of validation errors. You then test that, and respond appropriately. So, I'd change your controller to something like:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response create(@Valid UserDTO userDTO, BindingResult bindingResult, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
  if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    return Response... // some error code, or however you want to handle validation errors
  }

  User user = UserParser.parse(userDTO);
  userService.save(user);
  final URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(String.valueOf(user.getId())).build();
  return Response.created(uri).build();
}
```

It's probably not an issue right now, but if you add a `@ModelAttribute` annotated parameter to your method, bear in mind that the `BindingResult` parameter needs to appear immediately after it, otherwise things don't work. I can't remember the exact problem you see if you don't do it, but it's tricky to find if you don't know the above. I've definitely seen it documented in the Spring docs somewhere, but can't find anything other than [this forum post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/79880-an-interesting-finding-modelattribute-bindingresult) right now.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that as well. And even if it worked, which it doesn't, I don't like that approach, because then I have to pollute all my methods with this BindingResult, and even worse, check the result by myself, which pollutes the code further, and which is what validations should avoid in the first place.

Comment: I take your point that it's not as elegant as it could be, but I'm interested that you say it doesn't work. In what way does it not work? I think that might help you find the root cause of your problem.